# Unix command to find non-ascii chars

Tags: file, unix, command, non-ascii-characters

I have a file 500MB of size. 
It has some non-ascii characters in it. I just want to find out those characters using Unix command. May it will be better to get the line numbers and position at each line.

Thanks :)

Comment: You might find an answer here at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001177/how-do-i-grep-for-non-ascii-characters-in-unix

Comment: @vpit3833: am not very familiar with unix commands, I think that link does not provides the line numbers of those non-ascii chars. am sorry if am wrong...

Answer (score 3):

Use the answer given in [the other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001177/how-do-i-grep-for-non-ascii-characters-in-unix), but add `-n` to `grep`.

Answer (score 2):

You know, it's weird. Sometimes I find it faster to code up some quick and dirty C than it is to try and navigate the wilderness of UNIX utility command line options :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    size_t ln = 1;
    size_t chpos = 0;
    int chr;
    while ((chr = fgetc (stdin)) != EOF) {
        if (chr == '\n') {
            ln++;
            chpos = 0;
            continue;
        }
        chpos++;
        if (chr > 127) {
            printf ("Non-ASCII %02x found at line %d, offset %d\n",
                chr, ln, chpos);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This will give you both the line number, and the character position within that line, of any characters outside the ASCII range.