# find files with non-ascii chars in file name

Tags: find, non-ascii-characters

Is there a way I can `find` files with non-ascii chars? I could use a pipe of course - and filter the files with perl, but for efficiency I'd like to set it all in `find`. I tried the following:

```
find . -type f -name '*[^[:ascii:]]*'
```

it doesn't work at all.

**Edit**:

I'm now trying to make use of

```
find . -type f -regex '.*[^[:ascii:]].*'
```

It is an emacs regexp and it has `[:ascii:]` class. But the expression I'm trying to use doesn't work.

**Edit 2**:

```
LC_COLLATE=C find . -type f -regex '.*[^!-~].*'
```

matches files with non-ascii chars (a complete voodoo...). But also matches files with a space in the name.

Comment: Please check the manual to make it interpret the string as extended regex. Also check whether extended regex support the syntax.

Comment: Wow, I never heard of that. Now I'm trying to make work `find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '[^[:ascii:]]'`

Comment: It says `find: Invalid character class name`. Where do I find a list of posix-extended char classes?

Comment: Check this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Extended_Regular_Expressions

Comment: So posix doesn't have a `[:ascii:]` class.

Comment: Related: [How do I grep for all non-ASCII characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3001177/55075) & [find and delete files with non-ascii names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19146240/55075).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to work for me in both default and posix-extended mode:

```
LC_COLLATE=C find . -regex '.*[^ -~].*'
```

There could be locale-related issues, though, and I don't have a large corpus of non-ascii filenames to test it on, but it catches the ones I have.

Comment: Found this, which shows how to work around locale settings: (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3208902/1424666)

Comment: This is a strange character class. What does it mean? I never saw such things.

Comment: You must have been forgotten something: `find . '.*[^!-~].*'` - matches all the file and then says `find: \`.*[^!-~].*': No such file or directory`. `find . -regex '.*[^!-~].*'` gives `find: Invalid range end`.

Comment: @Adobe: Can you include your OS? Different flavor can have slightly different syntax.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Kubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to include the -regex option in the example. Did you try as described in the link I pasted?`LC_COLLATE=C find . -regex '.*[^ -~].*'`

Comment: I tried this: `LC_COLLATE=C find . -type f -regex '.*[^[:ascii:]].*'`. It gives strange results... Now I'm trying Yours.

Comment: See Edit2 of the original post. It mostly solves it.