# find and delete files with non-ascii names

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have some old migrated files that contain non-printable characters. I would like to find all files with such names and delete them completely from the system.

Example:

```
ls -l
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cws cws      0 Dec 28  2011 ??"??

ls -lb
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cws cws      0 Dec 28  2011 \a\211"\206\351
```

I would like to find all such files.

Here is an example screenshot of what I'm seeing when I do a `ls` in such folders:

[image]

I want to find these files with the non-printable characters and just delete them.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Non-ASCII characters

ASCII character codes range from `0x00` to `0x7F` in hex. Therefore, any character with a code greater than `0x7F` is a non-ASCII character. This includes the bulk of the characters in UTF-8 (ASCII codes are essentially a subset of UTF-8). For example, the Japanese character

> あ

is encoded in hex in UTF-8 as

> E3 81 82

UTF-8 has been the default character encoding on, among others, [Red Hat Linux since version 8.0 (2002), SuSE Linux since version 9.1 (2004), and Ubuntu Linux since version 5.04 (2005)](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#linux).

## ASCII control characters

Out of the ASCII codes, `0x00` through `0x1F` and `0x7F` represent control characters such as `ESC` (`0x1B`). These control characters were not originally intended to be printable even though some of them, like the line feed character `0x0A`, can be interpreted and displayed.

On my system, `ls` displays all control characters as `?` by default, unless I pass the `--show-control-chars` option. I'm guessing that the files you want to delete contain ASCII control characters, as opposed to non-ASCII characters. This is an important distinction: if you delete filenames containing non-ASCII characters, you may blow away legitimate files that just happen to be named in another language.

## Regular expressions for character codes

### POSIX

POSIX provides a very handy collection of character classes for dealing with these types of characters (thanks to [bashophil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2622293/bashophil) for pointing this out):

```
[:cntrl:] Control characters
[:graph:] Graphic printable characters (same as [:print:] minus the space character)
[:print:] Printable characters (same as [:graph:] plus the space character)
```

### PCRE

*Perl Compatible Regular Expressions* allow hexadecimal character codes using the syntax

```
\x00
```

For example, a PCRE regex for the Japanese character `あ` would be

```
\xE3\x81\x82
```

In addition to the POSIX character classes listed above, PCRE also provides the `[:ascii:]` character class, which is a convenient shorthand for `[\x00-\x7F]`.

GNU's version of `grep` supports PCRE using the `-P` flag, but BSD `grep` (on Mac OS X, for example) does not. Neither GNU nor BSD `find` supports PCRE regexes.

## Finding the files

GNU `find` supports POSIX regexes (thanks to [iscfrc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2840654/iscfrc) for pointing out the pure `find` solution to avoid spawning additional processes). The following command will list all filenames (but not directory names) below the current directory that contain non-printable control characters:

```
find -type f -regextype posix-basic -regex '^.*/[^/]*[[:cntrl:]][^/]*$'
```

The regex is a little complicated because the `-regex` option has to match the entire file path, not just the filename, and because I'm assuming that we don't want to blow away files with normal names simply because they are inside directories with names containing control characters.

To delete the matching files, simply pass the `-delete` option to `find`, *after all other options* (this is critical; passing `-delete` as the first option will blow away everything in your current directory):

```
find -type f -regextype posix-basic -regex '^.*/[^/]*[[:cntrl:]][^/]*$' -delete
```

I **highly** recommend running the command *without* the `-delete` first, so you can see what will be deleted before it's too late.

If you also pass the `-print` option, you can see what is being deleted as the command runs:

```
find -type f -regextype posix-basic -regex '^.*/[^/]*[[:cntrl:]][^/]*$' -print -delete
```

To blow away any *paths* (files *or* directories) that contain control characters, the regex can be simplified and you can drop the `-type` option:

```
find -regextype posix-basic -regex '.*[[:cntrl:]].*' -print -delete
```

With this command, if a directory name contains control characters, even if none of the filenames inside the directory do, they will *all* be deleted.

---

## Update: Finding both non-ASCII *and* control characters

It looks like your files contain both non-ASCII characters *and* ASCII control characters. As it turns out, `[:ascii:]` is *not* a POSIX character class, but it *is* provided by PCRE. I couldn't find a POSIX regex to do this, so it's Perl to the rescue. We'll still use `find` to traverse our directory tree, but we'll pass the results to Perl for processing.

To make sure we can handle filenames containing newlines (which seems likely in this case), we need to use the `-print0` argument to `find` (supported on both GNU and BSD versions); this separates records with a null character (`0x00`) instead of a newline, since the null character is the only character that can't be in a valid filename on Linux. We need to pass the corresponding flag `-0` to our Perl code so it knows how records are separated. The following command will print every path inside the current directory, recursively:

```
find . -print0 | perl -n0e 'print $_, "\n"'
```

Note that this command only spawns a single instance of the Perl interpreter, which is good for performance. The starting path argument (in this case, `.` for `CWD`) is optional in GNU `find` but is required in BSD `find` on Mac OS X, so I've included it for the sake of portability.

Now for our regex. Here is a PCRE regex matching names that contain either non-ASCII or non-printable (i.e. control) characters (or both):

```
[[:^ascii:][:cntrl:]]
```

The following command will print all *paths* (directories *or* files) in the current directory that match this regex:

```
find . -print0 | perl -n0e 'chomp; print $_, "\n" if /[[:^ascii:][:cntrl:]]/'
```

The `chomp` is necessary because it strips off the trailing null character from each path, which would otherwise match our regex. To delete the matching files and directories, we can use the following:

```
find . -print0 | perl -MFile::Path=remove_tree -n0e 'chomp; remove_tree($_, {verbose=>1}) if /[[:^ascii:][:cntrl:]]/'
```

This will also print out what is being deleted as the command runs (although control characters are interpreted so the output will not quite match the output of `ls`).

Comment: Additionally you could also use `[:print:]` or `[:graph:]`, see http://www.faqs.org/docs/abs/HTML/regexp.html

Comment: You're welcome. I was going to construct an answer myself but you were faster :)

I like the use of execdir.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. When I try [^[:ascii:]], I get find: Invalid character class name. Any idea what could cause that?

Comment: I tried the suggestions in this answer, but unfortunately, they havent been able to track the files with the non-printable characters in their names. I have just updated my question to include a screenshot if that will help anyone tweak this :)

Comment: @RohitChopra Apparently, `[:ascii:]` is not POSIX after all. See my update for another solution.

Comment: In cases you `find` without `-type f` it might make sense to add `-mindepth 1` to not delete the directory itself :)

Answer (score 6):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10806594/55075), try:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -regex '.*[^ -~].*' -print # -delete
```

or:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -type f -regex '*[^[:alnum:][:punct:]]*' -print # -delete
```

<sup>Note: After files are printed right, remove the `#` character.</sup>

See also: [How do I grep for all non-ASCII characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3001177/55075).

Answer (score 3):

By now, you probably have solved your question, but it didn't work well for my case, as I had files that was not being shown by `find` when I used the `-regex` switch. So I developed this workaround using `ls`. Hope it can be useful to someone.

Basically, what worked for me was this:

```
ls -1 -R -i | grep -a "[^A-Za-z0-9_.':@ /-]" | while read f; do inode=$(echo "$f" | cut -d ' ' -f 1); find -inum "$inode" -delete; done
```

Breaking it in parts:

```
ls -1 -R -i
```

This will recursively (`-R`) list (`ls`) files under current directory, one file per line (`-1`), prefixing each file by its inode number (`-i`). Results will be piped to `grep`.

```
grep -a "[^A-Za-z0-9_.':@ /-]"
```

Filter each entry considering each input as text (`-a`), even when it is eventually binary. `grep` will let a line pass if it contains a character different from the specified in the list. Results will be piped to `while`.

```
while read f
do
    inode=$(echo "$f" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
    find -inum "$inode" -delete
done
```

This `while` will iterate through all entries, extracting the inode number and passing the inode to `find`, which will then delete the file.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use PCRE with grep -P, just not with find (unfortunately).  You can chain find with grep using exec.  With PCRE (perl regex), we can use the ascii class and find any char that is non-ascii.

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c "echo \"{}\" | grep -qP '[^[:ascii:]]'" \; -exec rm {} \;
```

The following exec will not execute unless the first one returns a non-error code.  In this case, it means the expression matched the filename.  I used sh -c because -exec doesn't like pipes.

Answer (score 0):

You could print only lines containing a backslash with grep:

```
ls -lb | grep \\\\
```

Comment: This needs to be recursive. There are hundreds of folders within folders with such files