# How to find non-printable characters in the file?

Tags: file, grep, find, non-ascii-characters

I tried to find out the unprintable characters in data filein unix.
Code :

```
#!/bin/ksh
export SRCFILE='/data/temp1.dat'
while read line 
do
len=lenght($line)
for( $i = 0; $i < $len; $i++ ) {

        if( ord(substr($line, $i, 1)) > 127 )
        {
            print "$line\n";
            last;
        }
done < $SRCFILE
```

The code is not working , please help me in getting a solution for the above query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I grep for all non-ASCII characters in UNIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001177/how-do-i-grep-for-all-non-ascii-characters-in-unix)

Comment: Also dup of: [find and delete files with non-ascii names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19146240/55075).

Answer (score 17):

You can use `grep` for finding non-printable characters in a file, something like the following, which finds all non-printable-ASCII and all non-ASCII:

```
grep -P -n "[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\xFF]" input_file
```

`-P` gives you the more powerful Perl regular expressions (PCREs) and `-n` shows line numbers.

If your `grep` doesn't support PCREs, I'd just use Perl for this directly:

```
perl -ne '$x++;if($_=~/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\xFF]/){print"$x:$_"}' input_file
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your information but the grep command didnt work. Actually I wanted to find the non printable characaters inthe file  Please help if you can

Comment: The range `\x80-\xFF` covers non-ASCII but the OP asks for unprintable characters which, in the context of ASCII, also includes `\x00-\x1F`.

Comment: The first grep is missing an 'x'.  I cannot edit to only change 1 character here

Comment: @bjornruffians: thanks for that, I've added the `x` in.

Answer (score 14):

You may try something like this :

```
grep '[^[:print:]]' filePath
```

Comment: can you provide some part of file as example. Again you want to show the lines containing those character or ?

Comment: HI Smith,  Please find the below record

Comment: ABC|111112 | ATTEMPTED  | INDIA | AUSTRALIA | ENGLAND
ABC|222222 | ATTEMPTED ^Z | INDIA | AUSTRALIA | ENGLAND
ABC|333333 | ATTEMPTED  | INDIA | AUSTRALIA | ENGLADN
ABC|444444 | ROMATIC ^Z | INDIA | AUSTRALIA | ENGLADN

Comment: In the above record i need to populate the record # 2 and 4 as they contains unprintable characters and records 1 and 3 look fine .

Comment: You need to use `[^[:print:][:blank:]]` if you don't wish to include spaces/tabs.

Answer (score -3):

This sounds pretty trite but I was not sure how to do it just now.
I have become fond of "od" depending on what you are doing you may want something suited to printing arbitrary characters. The awk code is not very elegant but it is flexible if you are looking for specifics, the point is just to show the use of od however. Note the problems with awk compares and the spaces etc,

```
cat filename | od -A n -t x1z | awk '{ p=0; i=1; if ( NF>16) { while (i<17) {if ( $i!="0d"){ if ( $i!="0a") {if ( $i" " < "20 " ) {print $i ; p=1;}  if ( $i" "> "7f "){print $i;   p=1;}}}  i=i+1} if (p==1) print $0; }}' | more
```