# Searching for non-ascii characters

Tags: linux, unicode, grep

I have a file, a.out, which contains a number of lines. Each line is one character only, either the unicode character `U+2013` or a lower case letter `a-z`.

Doing a file command on a.out elicits the result UTF-8 Unicode text.

The locale command reports:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

If I issue the command `grep -P -n "[^\x00-\xFF]" a.out` I would expect only the lines containing `U+2013` to be returned. And this is the case if I carry out the test under cygwin. The problem environment however is Oracle Linux Server release 6.5 and the issue is that the grep command returns no lines. If I issue `grep -P -n "[\x00-\xFF]`" a.out then all lines are returned.

I realise that "`[grep -P]`...is highly experimental and `grep -P` may warn of unimplemented features." but no warnings are issued.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend avoiding dodgy `grep -P` implementations and use the real thing. This works:

```
perl -CSD -nle 'print "$.: $_" if /\P{ASCII}/' utfile1 utfile2 utfile3 ...
```

Where:

- The `-CSD` options says that both the stdio trio (stdin, stdout, stderr) and disk files should be treated as UTF-8 encoded.
- The `$.` represents the current record (line) number.
- The `$_` represents the current line.
- The `\P{ASCII}` matches any code point that is **not** ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

A comment in [How Do I grep For all non-ASCII Characters in UNIX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3001626/4518274) gives the answer:

> Grep (and family) don't do Unicode processing to merge multi-byte characters into a single entity for regex matching as you seem to want.

That implies that the UTF-8 encoding for `U+2013` (`0xe2`, `0x80`, `0x93`) is not treated by grep as parts of a single printable character outside the given range.

The GNU grep manual's d[escription of `-P`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#grep-Programs) does not mention Unicode or UTF-8.  Rather, it says *Interpret the pattern as a Perl regular expression.* (this does not mean that the result is *identical* to Perl, only that some of the backslash-escapes are *similar*).

Perl itself can be *told* to use UTF-8 encoding.  However the examples using Perl in [Filtering invalid utf8](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6516/filtering-invalid-utf8) do not use that feature.  Instead, the expressions (like those in the problematic grep) test only the individual bytes -- not the complete character.

Comment: Right. My understanding is that is why I have to use the -P option.

Answer (score 0):

gawk can help you for this problem,

here is the awk one-liner:

```
 awk -v FS="" 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<128;i++)ord[sprintf("%c",i)]=i}
               {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(!($i in ord))print $i}' file
```

below is a test with gawk:

```
kent$  cat f
abcd
+ß
s+äö
ö--我
中文

kent$  awk -v FS="" 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<128;i++)ord[sprintf("%c",i)]=i}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(!($i in ord))print $i}' f
ß
ä
ö
ö
我
中
文
```