# line return in grep search?

Tags: linux, grep

I have some files with the text:

```
xxxxx
xxxxx
<cert>
</cert>
some other stuff
```

How can I search with grep and ignore the line returns?
I have many files in the same folder.
I have tried this but it does not seem to stop running:

```
tr '\n' ' ' | grep '<cert></cert>' *
```

Comment: Add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Use GNU grep for this job.

Answer (score 1):

That is searching for a multi-line pattern, which the usual `grep` does not *appear* to support.  There are alternative tools, e.g.,

- *[How can I search for a multiline pattern in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152708/how-can-i-search-for-a-multiline-pattern-in-a-file)*, which suggests [pcregrep](http://www.pcre.org/), or custom awk, perl scripts.
- *[How can I “grep” patterns across multiple lines?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112132/how-can-i-grep-patterns-across-multiple-lines)*, again suggesting pcregrep (as well as sed scripts).

However, GNU grep is *said* to support this as well:

- *[How do I grep for multiple patterns on multiple lines?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551338/how-do-i-grep-for-multiple-patterns-on-multiple-lines)* gives as an example

  `grep -Pzo "^begin\$(.|\n)*^end$"` *file*

to use a newline in a pattern.  The options used however include the "experimental" `-P` which may make it less suitable than `pcregrep`:

> **`-P, --perl-regexp`**
>
> Interpret  *PATTERN* as a Perl regular expression.  This is highly
>   experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.
>
> **`-z, --null-data`**
>
> Treat  the  input  as  a set of lines, each terminated by a zero
>   byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline.   Like  the
>   -Z  or --null option, this option can be used with commands like
>   sort -z to process arbitrary file names.
>
> **`-o, --only-matching`**
>
> Print only the matched (non-empty) parts  of  a  matching  line,
>   with each such part on a separate output line.

Some experimental options are useful, others less so.  This one was noted as the source of problems in *[Searching for non-ascii characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29600466/searching-for-non-ascii-characters)*.