# Print non-ascii/unicode characters in shell

Tags: linux, shell, unicode, non-ascii-characters

I am using following command to search and print non-ascii characters:

```
grep --color -R -C 2 -P -n "[\x80-\xFF]" .
```

The output that I get, prints the line which has non-ascii characters in it.
However it does not print the actual unicode character.

Is there a way to print the unicode character?

### output

```
./test.yml-35-
./test.yml-36-- name: Flush Handlers
./test.yml:37:  meta: flush_handlers
./test.yml-38-
--
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was answered in [Searching for non-ascii characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29600466/searching-for-non-ascii-characters/29601507#29601507).  The real issue as shown in *[Filtering invalid utf8](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6516/filtering-invalid-utf8)* is that the regular expression you are using is for single bytes, while UTF-8 is a multibyte encoding (and the pattern must therefore cover multiple bytes).

The extensive [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12545/105132) by @[Peter O](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/2343/peter-o) in the latter Q/A appears to be the best one, using Perl.  grep is the wrong tool.