# How do you remove all non-ascii characters (character codes 128-255)?

Tags: unix

I've been recently introduced to shell scripting and would like to know the utility to delete all non-ascii characters. And most notably how to replace the ascii characters from (1 -31) with it's control char.

Comment: Which Unix and which shell? And what does “replace the ascii characters from (1 -31) with it's control char” mean?

Comment: like for example backspace would print out "^H" or cancel would print out "^X" like on this ascii table here http://www.physics.udel.edu/~watson/scen103/ascii.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to go with `tr` command (translate characters)

If you want to keep only "ascii chars" except those between 128 and 255 in your `a.in` file with Unix:

```
cat a.in | tr -cd '\128-\255'
```

If you wan to remove "ascii chars" that are not between 32 and 255:

```
cat a.in | tr -d '\0-\31' |tr -d '\255-\377'
```

Maybe the answer of [How do I grep for all non-ASCII characters in UNIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001177/how-do-i-grep-for-all-non-ascii-characters-in-unix) could also  be of some help.