# Whitebox appears in text in Google Chrome on Windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome

Here's what I know so far:

Browser: Google Chrome 56+
OS: Windows 10

The issue is in the picture, a white box appears inline with the text. When you inspect it the inspector shows a box character. I have tried on Chrome 55 and under and there is no issue. It's on the home page of our site, so people are quickly noticing it. Nothing in IE. Any ideas?

[image: Inline White Boxes]

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Stack Overflow removes special characters, so the code snippet below does not work.  See http://codepen.io/dennishall/pen/pRMxbJ for a working example.

EDIT 2: This S.O. post to find non-ascii characters should put you on the right track to find the problem file, if it's in your source code .. if not, it's in the CMS, and you should be able to figure out what record & field is the offender. -- [How do I grep for all non-ASCII characters in UNIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001177/how-do-i-grep-for-all-non-ascii-characters-in-unix)

```js
var stringWithSpecialCharacter = "find your";

document.getElementById('example-output').innerHTML = 'regular space char code = ' + stringWithSpecialCharacter.charCodeAt(4) + ' special character code for the following empty space = ' + stringWithSpecialCharacter.charCodeAt(5);
```

```html
<div id="example-output"></div>
```

You have a special character in your source code (or CMS).  Check your source code.  This might be from copy/paste from a Word doc or similar.